# Laplace equation on a circular domain, has my lecturer made a mistake?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, polar-coordinates, laplacian

The general solution to the Laplace equation, in polar cooridnates, on a circular domain is given by: $$U(r,\theta) = a_0+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}r^m(a_m\cos(m\theta) +b_m\sin(m\theta))$$

The coefficients, $a_0$,$a_m$ and $b_m$ can all be found by doing some integrals relating to the boundary condition, $f(\theta) =U(r_*,\theta)$
What follows is ideas that my lecturer has put forward, which I do not fully understand. I will endeavour to write exactly as my lecturer has so that you may understand.

We can evaluat $U(r,\theta)$ at $r=r_*$ which would lead to $$U(r_*,\theta) = a_0+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}r_*^m(a_m\cos(m\theta) +b_m\sin(m\theta))=f(\theta)$$ I assume the use of this is so that we can compare the series to the boundary and use that to 'extract' the Fourier coefficients.

Returning to the first equation, it has been given to us that we can find the values of the coefficients as follows: $$a_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(\theta)d\theta $$
$$a_m = \frac{1}{\pi r_*^m}\int_0^{2\pi}f(\theta)\cos(m\theta)d\theta $$
$$b_m = \frac{1}{\pi r_*^m}\int_0^{2\pi}f(\theta)\sin(m\theta)d\theta $$

My confusion comes from incorporating the $r_*^m$s in our general solution. In our lecture notes, we have been given two examples and they each treat the inclusion of $r_*$ differently.

Example $1$: Consider the piecewise defined boundary condition $$U(r_*,\theta)=\ \begin{cases} 
      U_1 & 0 < \theta \leq \pi \\
      U_2 & \pi <\theta <2\pi
   \end{cases}
\
$$
Where $U_1,U_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. We can use the above integrals to solve for the Fourier coefficients. I will only focus here on $b_m$ as $a_0$ is easy to compute and $a_m=0$.

My lecturers solution has said that $$b_m =\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(\theta)\sin(m\theta)d\theta$$
The details of the integral are not important here, but what I have concerns about is that they have said that $b_m = \frac{1}{\pi}\dots$, shouldn't it be that $b_m = \frac{1}{\pi r_*^m}\dots$, as was specified in the way of deriving the coefficients? This is carried forward and the final solution does not contain $r_*^m$ at all: $$U(r,\theta) = \frac{U_1+U_2}{2} + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{r^m}{m}(1-(-1)^m)\sin(m\theta) $$

Example $2$: This time we set $U(r_*,\theta) = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos(2\theta)$. This time $a_0 = \frac{1}{2},a_2=-\frac{1}{2r_*^2},a_m=0$ and $b_m=0$. This gives the solution: $$U(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{r^2}{2r_*^2}\cos(2\theta) $$ Note that this time the $r_*$ is included explicitly.

So that's my problem, is the exclusion of $r_*$ in the first example a mistake, or is there something more complicated that I am missing?

Comment: Could it be that in the first example the boundary condition was on the unit circle? This is the “usual” standard setting.

Comment: @TedShifrin It doesn't make reference to that anywhere within the problem.

Comment: To avoid this confusion, solve the problem taking $r_*=1$, and then in your final solution simply substitute $r\to r/r_*$.

Comment: @K.defaoite my problem is that my lecturer has been inconsistent with using $r_*$. My question is, do we always include it and my lecturer made a mistake or am I missing something?

Comment: @LexLuthor That's a question your lecturer can probably answer much better than I.

Comment: The final answer should contain $r^*$. I suspect the confusion is that: in the first solution, $r^*$ was set to one (a common practice- it can be reinstated later on dimensional grounds) while in the second solution it was left explicitly in. You aren't missing something